# Redirect output from function to File in C

Tags: c, file, redirect, output

I want to redirect some printf() from a function to a file.

I dont want to change the whole function. Instead I want something like this:

```
 void write_to_temp_File(struct s_28b_meta, struct s_db_entry);

file_name = "temp.txt";
handle_file = CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_WRITE, 0,NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL);

//sanity check
if(handle_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
printf("Could not open %s file, error %d\n", file_name, GetLastError());

//test check
test = GetHandleInformation(handle_file, lpdwFlags);
printf("The return value is %d, error %d\n", test, GetLastError());

//actually print into file
fprintf(handle_file, reader_print_db(byte **ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries, 1024));

//clean close and exit
CloseHandle(handle_file);
return 0;
```

So in fact, I want to open a file and redirect the output of all prints inside the function to the new created file.

In sysCall it would be something like:

```
text.exe > temp.txt
```

Is there a good way to do it and how can I get the length of the output of the function, instead of a static value like I have?

Thank you already

Comment: This is far from a [mcve]... I could not understand if the `[f]printf` are inside the function or if you want to write to the file something that is returned by the function, not if you want to write one single string or a bunch of individual values.

Comment: You could use `fprintf` in the function and pass `stdout` or another file pointer. Both `printf` and `fprintf` return the number of bytes written.

Comment: **Some** `printf()` calls but not others?  Rewrite the entire function to do what you want.

Comment: I see what you mean there guys, but I try to do a little workaround here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using freopen should help you.

```
freopen("temp.txt", "a+", stdout);
```

After reopening the stdout with freopen() all output statement `printf, putchar` are redirected to file `temp.txt`. So after that any `printf()` statement will redirect it's output to the `temp.txt` file.

reference:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen

Comment: Now, restore the original `stdout` stream for the code that runs *after* the function in question.

Comment: Thank you for the tip